# How to set text-overflow within bootstrap list-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set up a text-overflow property on links within a bootstrap list-group. There is also a bootstrap badge floated to the right of each list item within the group. When I try to set the text-overflow property, the link goes under the badge and is not truncated.
here is the code im trying to set. forum-link is a class attached to each a tag:

```
.forum-link 
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

here is the jsFiddle showing the code-http://jsfiddle.net/tdmoneybanks/c3hsa2y2/7/

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Needed to wrap my text within a div inside of the a tag.

Answer (score 1):

Add that to your code:

```
.list-group-item {
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I've updated your fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3hsa2y2/18/)

Answer (score 0):

Add display block and overflow hidden to anchor tag, this will help you if i get you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
.text_info{
  display:inline-block;
  width:90%;
  max-width:91%;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Just add this css and give class to your `<a>` tag.

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3hsa2y2/22/)

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just to contribute an up-to-date answer for Bootstrap 4 where this is easily accomplished with col and col-auto:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-truncate">
        This text could be very long and will be truncated if it doesn't fit
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">(icon)</div>
      <div class="col-auto">(icon)</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```